# Timesheet Script How to add days?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, calculator, jsfiddle

I'm using this script to calculate work hours:
https://jsfiddle.net/skootsa/bqm4uh79/1/

How do I simply add 2 days so that it calculates weekends as well? And how do I go about changing the numbers in the "row" to the days of the week? For example, instead of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7-- I'd like it to list Monday, Tues, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday etc.

**HTML**:

```
    <form name="ivForm">
  <div id="error_chunk" style="color:red;"></div>
  <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr style="background:#ddd;" class="header_row">
        <td>Row</td>
        <td>Starting Time (HH:MM)</td>
        <td>Ending Time (HH:MM)</td>
        <td>Lunch/Breaks(HH:MM)</td>
        <td>Calculated Total</td>
      </tr>

      <tr style="background:#eee;">
        <td><u>1</u></td>
        <td>
          <input name="start_hr1" value="00" class="t1" onchange="if(!this.init) this.init=1; return calc(this)" accesskey="1"> :
          <input name="start_min1" value="00" class="t1" onchange="return calc(this)">
          <select name="start_time1" onchange="return calc(this)">
            <option>AM</option>
            <option>PM </option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="end_hr1" value="00" class="t1" onchange="if(!this.init){ this.init=1; this.form.end_time1.options.selectedIndex=1; }; return calc(this)"> :
          <input name="end_min1" value="00" class="t1" onchange="return calc(this)">
          <select name="end_time1" onchange="return calc(this)">
            <option>AM</option>
            <option>PM </option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="break_hr1" value="00" class="t1" onchange="return calc(this)"> :
          <input name="break_min1" value="00" class="t1" onchange="return calc(this)"> </td>
        <td>
          <div id="stot1">0.00</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="background:#eee;">
        <td><u>2</u></td>
        <td>
          <input name="start_hr2" value="00" class="t1" onchange="if(!this.init) this.init=1; return calc(this)" accesskey="2"> :
          <input name="start_min2" value="00" class="t1" onchange="return calc(this)">
          <select name="start_time2" onchange="return calc(this)">
            <option>AM</option>
            <option>PM </option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="end_hr2" value="00" class="t1" onchange="if(!this.init){ this.init=1; this.form.end_time2.options.selectedIndex=1; }; return calc(this)"> :
          <input name="end_min2" value="00" class="t1" onchange="return calc(this)">
          <select name="end_time2" onchange="return calc(this)">
            <option>AM</option>
            <option>PM </option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="break_hr2" value="00" class="t1" onchange="return calc(this)"> :
          <input name="break_min2" value="00" class="t1" onchange="return calc(this)"> </td>
        <td>
          <div id="stot2">0.00</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="background:#eee;">
        <td><u>3</u></td>
        <td>
          <input name="start_hr3" value="00" class="t1" onchange="if(!this.init) this.init=1; return calc(this)" accesskey="3"> :
          <input name="start_min3" value="00" class="t1" onchange="return calc(this)">
          <select name="start_time3" onchange="return calc(this)">
            <option>AM</option>
            <option>PM </option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="end_hr3" value="00" class="t1" onchange="if(!this.init){ this.init=1; this.form.end_time3.options.selectedIndex=1; }; return calc(this)"> :
          <input name="end_min3" value="00" class="t1" onchange="return calc(this)">
          <select name="end_time3" onchange="return calc(this)">
            <option>AM</option>
            <option>PM </option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="break_hr3" value="00" class="t1" onchange="return calc(this)"> :
          <input name="break_min3" value="00" class="t1" onchange="return calc(this)"> </td>
        <td>
          <div id="stot3">0.00</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="background:#eee;">
        <td><u>4</u></td>
        <td>
          <input name="start_hr4" value="00" class="t1" onchange="if(!this.init) this.init=1; return calc(this)" accesskey="4"> :
          <input name="start_min4" value="00" class="t1" onchange="return calc(this)">
          <select name="start_time4" onchange="return calc(this)">
            <option>AM</option>
            <option>PM </option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="end_hr4" value="00" class="t1" onchange="if(!this.init){ this.init=1; this.form.end_time4.options.selectedIndex=1; }; return calc(this)"> :
          <input name="end_min4" value="00" class="t1" onchange="return calc(this)">
          <select name="end_time4" onchange="return calc(this)">
            <option>AM</option>
            <option>PM </option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="break_hr4" value="00" class="t1" onchange="return calc(this)"> :
          <input name="break_min4" value="00" class="t1" onchange="return calc(this)"> </td>
        <td>
          <div id="stot4">0.00</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="background:#eee;">
        <td><u>5</u></td>
        <td>
          <input name="start_hr5" value="00" class="t1" onchange="if(!this.init) this.init=1; return calc(this)" accesskey="5"> :
          <input name="start_min5" value="00" class="t1" onchange="return calc(this)">
          <select name="start_time5" onchange="return calc(this)">
            <option>AM</option>
            <option>PM </option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="end_hr5" value="00" class="t1" onchange="if(!this.init){ this.init=1; this.form.end_time5.options.selectedIndex=1; }; return calc(this)"> :
          <input name="end_min5" value="00" class="t1" onchange="return calc(this)">
          <select name="end_time5" onchange="return calc(this)">
            <option>AM</option>
            <option>PM </option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="break_hr5" value="00" class="t1" onchange="return calc(this)"> :
          <input name="break_min5" value="00" class="t1" onchange="return calc(this)"> </td>
        <td>
          <div id="stot5">0.00</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5" align="right" id="stots"><b>Total Hrs = 0</b></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br>
  <input type="button" name="mcalc" value="Calculate" onclick="
  /* walk through the rows, use known input to generate cases for calc to operate on */
  f = this.form; for(var i=0; i<f.elements.length; i++){
    if(f.elements[i].name.match(/start_hr/)){ calc(f.elements[i]); }
  }  
  cal_days_sum()
">


</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    for (var i = 8; i < 6; i++) {
    var html = '' + '  <tr style="background:#eee;">' + '    <td><u>' + i + '</u></td>' + '    <td><input name="start_hr' + i + '" value="00" class="t1" onchange="if(!this.init) this.init=1; return calc(this)" accesskey="' + i + '"> :' + '        <input name="start_min' + i + '" value="00" class="t1" onchange="return calc(this)"> ' + '        <select name="start_time' + i + '" onchange="return calc(this)">' + '        <option>AM<option>PM' + '        </select>' + '    </td>' + '    <td><input name="end_hr' + i + '" value="00" class="t1" onchange="if(!this.init){ this.init=1; this.form.end_time' + i + '.options.selectedIndex=1; }; return calc(this)"> :' + '        <input name="end_min' + i + '" value="00" class="t1" onchange="return calc(this)"> ' + '        <select name="end_time' + i + '" onchange="return calc(this)">' + '        <option>AM<option>PM' + '        </select>' + '    </td>' + '    <td><input name="break_hr' + i + '" value="00" class="t1" onchange="return calc(this)"> :' + '        <input name="break_min' + i + '" value="00" class="t1" onchange="return calc(this)"> ' + '    </td>' + '    <td><div id="stot' + i + '"></div></td>' + '  </tr>'
    document.write(html)
  }
  //-->









    err = function(msg, obj) {
      /* global error handler */
      errobj = document.getElementById('error_chunk')
      errobj.innerHTML = msg
      if (obj) {
        window.errObj = obj;
        setTimeout('if(window.errObj.focus){window.errObj.focus();}if(window.errObj.select){window.errObj.select();} window.errObj=0;', 250)
      }
      return false;
    }


    validate = function(obj) {
      tmp = parseInt(obj.value)
        //if(tmp.length<1) obj.value='00'; return

      if (obj.name.match(/(start|end)_min/)) {
        if (tmp < 0 || tmp > 59) {
          return err('Minutes must be between 00 and 59', obj);
        }
      } else if (obj.name.match(/(start|end)_hr/) && obj.init) {
        if (tmp < 1 || tmp > 12) {
          return err('Hour must be between 01 and 12', obj);
        }
      }
    }


    cal_days_sum = function() {
      /* sum the hours column(s) and give a total of the hours shown -- mainly for multiple days */
      if (!this.arr) {
        this.arr = new Array()
        var tmparr = document.getElementsByTagName('div')
        for (var i = 0; i < tmparr.length; i++) {
          if (tmparr[i].id.match(/^stot/)) this.arr.push(tmparr[i])
        }
      }
      var sum = 0
      for (var i = 0; i < this.arr.length; i++) {
        sum += parseFloat(this.arr[i].innerHTML)
      }
      obj = document.getElementById('stots')
      obj.innerHTML = '<b>Total Hrs = ' + sum + '</b>'
    }


    calc = function(obj) {
      /* get the sibling objects */
      objN = obj.name.match(/\d+$/); //get the object number so we can find it's siblings
      f = obj.form
      start_hr = eval('f.start_hr' + objN)
      start_min = eval('f.start_min' + objN)
      start_time = eval('f.start_time' + objN)
      end_hr = eval('f.end_hr' + objN)
      end_min = eval('f.end_min' + objN)
      end_time = eval('f.end_time' + objN)
      break_hr = eval('f.break_hr' + objN)
      break_min = eval('f.break_min' + objN)


      /* validate hour and minute limits */
      err(''); /* clear error */
      t = start_hr;
      validate(t)
      t = start_min;
      validate(t)
      t = end_hr;
      validate(t)
      t = end_min;
      validate(t)
      t = break_hr;
      validate(t)
      t = break_min;
      validate(t)


      /* convert to 24 hour */
      start_hr.val = parseInt(start_hr.value); //force it to be a number
      if (start_time.options[start_time.selectedIndex].text.match(/PM/, 'i')) start_hr.val += 12;
      end_hr.val = parseInt(end_hr.value);
      if (end_hr.val == 12) end_hr.val += 0;
      else if (end_time.options[end_time.selectedIndex].text.match(/PM/, 'i')) end_hr.val += 12;
      break_hr.val = parseInt(break_hr.value);
      tot_hr = (end_hr.val - start_hr.val - break_hr.val)

      /* convert minutes from 60 to 100 */
      start_min.val = parseFloat(start_min.value) / 60
      end_min.val = parseFloat(end_min.value) / 60
      break_min.val = parseFloat(break_min.value) / 60
      tot_min = (end_min.val - start_min.val - break_min.val)

      /* accommodate graveyard */
      if (start_hr.val > end_hr.val) {
        end_hr.val += 24
        tot_hr = (end_hr.val - start_hr.val)
      }

      t = parseFloat(parseFloat(tot_hr) + parseFloat(tot_min))
      if (t < 0) t = 'NA'
      else {
        // need a decimal point + two digits to it's right
        if (!t.toString().match(/\./)) t += '.00'
        else if (!t.toString().match(/.+\.[0-9][0-9]/)) {
          t += '00'
        }
        t = t.toString().match(/.+\.[0-9][0-9]/)
      }
      //alert(start_hr.val +'--'+ end_hr.val+'--tot_hr='+tot_hr+'--tot_min='+tot_min+'--t='+t)
      obj = document.getElementById('stot' + objN);
      if (errobj && errobj.innerHTML) t = 'NA'
      obj.innerHTML = t

      cal_days_sum()
    }

    /* start by forcing a calc */
    document.ivForm.mcalc.click()
      //-->
```

Comment: I  edited the HTML to create the 2 extra rows. But now the first 3 rows aren't calculating. Here's the updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/skootsa/v30LgwLj/6/

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array of days that you would then call using i as your index:

```
var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
```

`days[2]` outputs `Tuesday`

Rearrange them however you like corresponding to your loop.

Wouldn't you just add 48 hours to your final calculation to account for Saturday and Sunday?

Comment: Asking respectfully, did you write this code yourself?

Comment: No, its a free snippet from this site: http://esqsoft.com/javascript/javascript-timesheet-calculator.htm and thats why im asking. I want to modify it, but im not skilled enough yet